# How do I programmatically clear the SearchBox control history in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-8.1

Windows 8.1 introduced a new control: [SearchBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.searchbox.aspx). It has a feature that remembers user searches which is good, but I want to allow the user to clear the search history. How do I implement that in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [`ClearHistory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.search.core.searchsuggestionmanager.clearhistory.aspx) method on the [`SearchSuggestionManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.search.core.searchsuggestionmanager.aspx) class that clears all search history contexts.

Code in C#:

```
var manager = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.Core.SearchSuggestionManager();
manager.ClearHistory();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing based on what little documentation is available, but have you tried toggling the SearchHistoryEnabled property?

I'm fairly certain changing the SearchHistoryContext would create a different history key and have the effect of hiding previous searches, but I doubt that would actually delete the history. Do you know where the search history is actually stored?